# Replace a specific value with another using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to replace a specific value or values with another value.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    hi     hello
AA  Q4.2022 1      0
BB  Q4.2022 1      1
CC  Q4.2022 HI111  1
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    hi     hello
AA  Q4.2022 1      0
BB  Q4.2022 1      1
CC  Q4.2022        1
```

**Doing**

I have using this statement, however, this deletes the all the values

```
df['hi'] = df['hi'].str.replace('HI111','')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: it works as intended when I try it

Comment: it is deleting all the other values - the entire column is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the numbers are int types; then you could try `to_numeric` + `isna` and use it in `mask`:

```
df['hi'] = df['hi'].mask(pd.to_numeric(df['hi'], errors='coerce').isna(), '')
```

or if you want to change the type of the numbers to strings as well, you could use `to_numeric` + `fillna` + `astype(str)`:

```
df['hi'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['hi'], errors='coerce').fillna('')
            .astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])
```

Output:

```
   ID     Date hi  hello
0  AA  Q4.2022  1      0
1  BB  Q4.2022  1      1
2  CC  Q4.2022         1
```